# Got compile error when using \U escape

Tags: c#, .net

I got a compile error 'unrecognized escape sequence' when using \U for unicode literal, is there anything wrong with my program?

```
  public class TestProject
{

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string s1 = "\UD800DC09";
  Console.WriteLine(s1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It says: "Unicode characters with code points above 0x10FFFF are not supported."

**EDIT**:
May be what you want is:

```
string s1 = "\uD800\uDC09";
```

Comment: Technically there are no Unicode characters with code points > 10FFFF as Unicode is  21-bit code.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes, the MSDN article said the upper case U '\U' can be followed with a 8-digit number as a valid unicode escape sequence, how can I got a compile error if so?

Comment: Yes, but only values up to 10ffff are valid. The value you're using, d800dc09, actually looks like a surrogate pair. I've seen Microsoft compilers mangle code points above ffff and display them like that before. What you probably want is \U00010009, which is the codepoint that has the surrogate representation D800 DC09.

Comment: @bames53, I've tried \U00010009, it's just what I want.So it means the 8-digit followed the \U is the code point, not a UTF-16 encoding.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a lowercase `u`.

```
string s1 = "\uD800DC09";
```

https://ideone.com/OIsC9

Comment: It's still a broken character, though.